# keeping hair "wet"?

Tags: hair

I'm a guy and have been experimenting with growing my hair out. My hair is very thick and wavy and by keeping it well-conditioned I've been able to keep it mostly under control while I've been growing it out. My issue is that I really like how it is when it's wet, it's not quite as wavy, it lays flatter, and just generally looks better. When it dries out, it gets more wavy and poofy and doesn't lay flat at all.

I've tried using leave-in conditioner and while that does seem to extend the wet-hair look, it's still dry by the time lunch comes around.

I don't really want to gel it in place so it gets hard and crusty, do I have any other options?

Comment: Mousse. Or better yet ask you hair professional.

Comment: Apply hair oil.

Comment: Brylcreem. A little dab'll do ya.

Answer (score 1):

There are products out there which won't make your hair hard and crusty, e.g. Hair Moisturizer, which essentially should only keep the hair moist.

Ideally, ask your barber about it, they have the best products, though usually they also cost more.

From quick search, you can also find such products on Amazon, e.g. [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B092XC4SZW).

One last tip, from own experience: don't go for the cheap stuff, this will indeed make the hair hard and crusty, even if saying otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Hair pomade or hair wax has been used for that purpose for about 70 years for guys. Something I personally have used is John Frieda’s Secret Weapon which I think is targeted at women or both genders. Not sure if it does what you want but my hair was thick and wavy and bigger than I liked for a long time. I’m female.

Comment: Technically hair pomade has already been used in the 17th and 18th century by men and women, but it fell out of fashion (at least in the western world). It comes in soft (oily) and hard (waxy) consistencies and it's very healthy for the hair.